# Monitoring tool for Ubuntu

Tags: server, firewall, dhcp, bandwidth, nat

I am running a Ubuntu server for NAT and DHCP services in my Office. What monitoring tool can be used to remotely monitor server performance, DHCP lease addresses, IP Lease statistics, monitor bandwidth per user etc?

I have searched on google for this but could not find appropriate one. Many other experts suggest nagios, cacti etc.

The community rocks!

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix and Icinga are two of our favorites. For a pros and cons list, check out [Five Of The Best Free Network Monitoring Software Tools](https://www.libertycenterone.com/blog/five-of-the-best-free-network-monitoring-software-tools/).